# Append Members to an Array in JSON with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I need to use Powershell to insert data into a json file within an array. Here is the json original structure

```
{
"Array": [
    {
        "servername": "foo"
    },
    {
        "servername": "boo"
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is the new structure:

```
   {
    "Array": [
        {
            "servername": "Foo",
            "Disk": "100"
        },
        {
            "servername": "Boo",
            "Disk": "500"
        }
    ]
   }
```

Why does this not work?

```
$json = @"
{
    "Array": [
        {
            "servername": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "servername": "Boo"
        }
        ]
    }
"@

$jsonServerFoo=@"
    {
    "Disk": "100"
    }
"@

$jsonServerBoo=@"
    {
    "Disk": "500"
    }
"@

$jsonObj = $JSON | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonServerFooObj = $jsonServerFoo | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonServerBooObj = $jsonServerBoo | ConvertFrom-Json
$i = 1 
$jsonObj.Array | Foreach-object {
    if ( $i -eq 1 ) {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disk" -Value $jsonServerFooObj.Disk
        $i++
    }
    else {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disk" -Value $jsonServerBooObj.Disk
    }
}
$jsonObj
$jsonObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

I get the desired output

```
{
    "Array":  [
                  {
                      "servername":  "Foo",
                      "Disk":  "100"
                  },
                  {
                      "servername":  "Boo",
                      "Disk":  "500"
                  }
              ]
}
```

Comment: With PS6 there is a “-AsHastable” property of Convert-FromJson which fixes this historic oversight..

Comment: Why did you edit the solution into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Add-Member` to add members to a `PSCustomObject`. `ConvertFrom-Json` returns a `PSCustomObject`, not a `Hashtable`.

```
$jsonObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -MemberName MyPropertyName -Value "some value, doesn't have to be a string"
```

You don't have to work with the base `$jsonObj` either, you can also add members to nested members of `$jsonObj` as well. In your case, with the `Array` member:

```
$jsonObj.Array | Foreach-object {
  if( $i -eq 1 ) {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disk -Value $jsonServerFooObj.Disk
    $i++
  } else {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disk -Value $jsonServerBooObj.Disk
  }
}
```

You may also want to consider calling `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100` so you don't get the default object depth which is low, 3 I think.

---

As noted by @user2864740, in PowerShell 6 `ConvertFrom-Json` has the `-AsHashtable` parameter if you would rather work with a `Hashtable` than a `PSCustomObject`.